# Largest sum of subset of a matrix with condition

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming, subset, subset-sum

I have a problem: Given a matrix A, find the (sub)set C with largest sum, which consists of a_{ij} elements of matrix A, such that no two members of C share the same column or same row in A.

So far I have not found the optimum solution to it, and I do not know what classifications it belongs. So please help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look for "Hungarian Algorithm" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I am looking for! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Wrote my B.A. thesis on it, sounded familiar. :-)

Comment: Hungarian algorithm is for square matrix, mine is probably a more relax case ...